# Python: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, swig

I used swig to create a python file from c. I have converted the c file into .py file and when I try to invoke a function of the c program, I am getting an error
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fact'

My C file is

```
/* File : example.c */


 #include <time.h>
 double My_variable = 3.0;

 int fact(int n) {
     if (n <= 1) return 1;
     else return n*fact(n-1);
 }

 int my_mod(int x, int y) {
     return (x%y);
 }

 char *get_time()
 {
     time_t ltime;
     time(&ltime);
     return ctime(&ltime);
 }
```

My interface file is

```
   /* example.i */
 %module example
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
 extern double My_variable;
 extern int fact(int n);
 extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
 extern char *get_time();
 %}
```

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **inline** your declarations in *example.i*:

```
%module example
%inline %{
```

From [[SWIG]: Inlined code blocks](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn43):

> The *%inline* directive inserts all of the code that follows verbatim into the header portion of an interface file.